# Damped wave equation on $\mathbb{R}^{2}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $a \in (0, 1)$ and let $u$ satisfy

\begin{align*}
u_{tt} - \Delta_{x}u + au_{t} &= 0\\
u(x,0) &= 0\\
u_{t}(x, 0) &= f(x)
\end{align*}

with $t \geq 0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}^{2}$, and $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}^{2})$. Let $$E(t) := \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}^{2}}|\nabla u|^{2} + |u_{t}|^{2}\, dx.$$ Then $$E'(t) = -a\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}^{2}}u_{t}^{2}\, dx.$$ Must $E(t)$ decrease exponentially in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint.  Use the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}^2 / (2 \pi \mathbb{Z})^2$ to write
$$
u(x,t) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \varphi_n(t) e^{i x \cdot n}.
$$ 
Plugging into the PDE then shows that 
$$
\ddot{\varphi}_n(t) + |n|^2 \varphi_n(t) +a \dot{\varphi}_n(t) =0 \\
\phi_n(0) =0 \text{ and } \dot{\phi}_n(0) = \hat{f}_n = \int f(x) e^{-ix\cdot n}dx.
$$
Solve the ODE and examine the resulting solutions as $n \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ varies.  Using this, you can say something about the behavior of $E(t)$.